# can we insert duplicate key in hashmap?

Tags: hashmap, weak-references

i done it using stringbuilder got the o/p as `{abc=value-bb, abc=value-cc, abc=value-aa, abc=value-abc}`

but wanted to know if it is possible by using Weak reference

Comment: Not clear on what you are trying to achieve. Do you meant want to use HashMap for producing the above output

Comment: yes but i have done using stringbuffer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;


class Hash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<StringBuffer, String> mp = new HashMap<StringBuffer, String>();
        mp.put(new StringBuffer("abc"),"value-abc");
        mp.put(new StringBuffer("abc"),"value-abc");
        mp.put(new StringBuffer("abc"),"value-abc");
        StringBuffer ojas= null;
        System.out.println(mp);
    }
}
```

Output

```
{abc=value-abc, abc=value-abc, abc=value-abc}
```